Snap and emby file permissions
When I use deb version of Emby I can reach my nfs with no problem, /mnt/main, when I try to use the snap version of emby, I received denied and it keeps pointing to /root/snap
I am new to Linux and Ununtu, so not that familiar with commands and file system yet.
The reason why I want to use the snap version it is updated automatically.

The SNAP removable-media interface documentation lists which top-level directories are considered to contain removable media:

removable-media allows read/write access to mounted removable storage in /media, /run/media and /mnt.
Access to /mnt requires snapd version 2.36+.

Therefore, running the following should allow the SNAP emby to access mount:
sudo snap connect emby:removable-media

Note: I don't have emby installed to test this, but this is based upon my answer in 24.04 Thunderbird claims "another instance is running" whereby giving Thunderbird SNAP removable-media allowed access to a directory under /mnt.

Thank you that worked!!!
